# Should I add Laravel vendor directory to .gitignore or not?

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php, gitignore

I'm having my vendor directory in `.gitignore` file.
 Every time I run `composer update` , git can not track `vendor` directory updates and changes and therefor I can not backward these changes!!

**My question is:**  Is it possible that application crash OR encounter errors after `composer update` so there is a need to `git reset`?

If it is possible, isn't it better to remove vendor  directory from `.gitignore` ?
maybe there are other solutions to this problem ? (if it is a problem at all !!)

Comment: Why'd you try to edit "Side note: composer dump-autoload shouldn't make any destructive changes in vendor" out of my answer? Do you believe that to be incorrect in some way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Composer provides the `composer.lock` file for this purpose.

Installing a new package, doing a `composer update`, etc. that causes package changes will write the exact versions of the installed packages to `composer.lock`. You should include this file in your repository's versioned files.

You can run `composer install` to automatically install the exact list of package versions from `composer.lock`. As it's going to be versioned, you can always roll it back to a working version and run `composer install` again.

Side note: `composer dump-autoload` shouldn't make any destructive changes in `vendor`.

Answer (score 11):

`vendor` directory is in `.gitignore` by default. And this is a good idea, because `composer` will install all packages it will find in `composer.json` for you on any machine at any time. If you have trouble with new version of some package, just change it back in `composer.json` and run `composer update` again.

Of course you can remove `vendor` directory from `.gitignore` but this will slow down commits and will use much more disk and GitHub/BitBucket space etc.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the `git commit`  slow down part. but package dependencies and versions are not just in the main `composer.json` file. every `vendor` package have a `composer.json` file and other dependencies.  is it easy to track the problematic package and change its version?

Comment: what about sharing the code between  team members? do I have to tell all members my changes to the `composer.json` file ?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki, both `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files will be commited by git.

Comment: The problem is there is no exact version in `composer.json` file! Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't think setting the exact version is the correct way! as `composer update` is meaning less by doing that

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin The `composer.lock` contains the exact versions. When a member of the team does `composer update` (or adds a new package, or removes one, etc.), they test, commit their updated `composer.lock` to the repo, and the other members of the team do a `composer install` to get the new package versions.

Comment: "but this will slow down commits and will use much more disk and GitHub/BitBucket space etc."

The vendor directory is a few megs compressed, it doesn't add any serious commit time or disk space. There are other reasons to not include the vendor directory, but I don't think those two are applicable in this day and age.

Personally, I include the vendor directory, as it makes deploys and consistency easier, and that is a much higher priority to me than small commit size or an extra second of upload/download on a project. Rollbacks/version checkouts are more consistent as well.

Comment: @Brettins do you still commit vendor folder to your repos? After a couple of years have you noticed any problems with that? Will you continue with this practice? How fast is it to pull a repo when the vendor folder is there as well? When you do a first checkout for example?

Comment: We actually run laravel/nova serverless on AWS and I can tell you, upload size definitely matters there.